# windows batch keep returning a sytax error: cant find the hitch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

just want my batch to rotate screen, open a program, and rotate back when closed:

```
REM starts by rotating the screen using a program called display64


START C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\display\display64.exe /rotate:90

REM then waits a time so the sceen has time to reorient on the monitor.

SLEEP 10

REM then launches the game

cd "C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2"
"Pinball FX2.exe"


REM   start a loop where the batch seees if the game is running and leaves the screen alone

:LOOP
    ECHO tasklist loop starting
    tasklist | FIND "Pinball FX2.exe" >nul
    IF %errorlevel% 1 (
        ECHO program not running anymore ---> rotate back!
        GOTO CONTINUE
        )  
    ECHO tasklist loop returned to start
    ELSE (
        ECHO pinfx2 still runnning, restarting loop
        TIMEOUT /T 5 /Nobreak
        GOTO LOOP
    )
ECHO tasklist loop returned showing its closed...stopping loop

REM   if the program closes, batch rotates the screen back

:CONTINUE

START C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\display\display64.exe /rotate:0


Exit 0
```

but I run the batch in a cmd window, with the verbose flag...and this (after forcekilling the game.
alt+f4):

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>"pinfx2 and rotate 90.cmd" -v

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>REM starts by rotating the screen using a program called display64
    
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>START C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\display\display64.exe /rotate:90

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>REM then waits a time so the sceen has time to reorient on the monitor.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>SLEEP 10
    
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>REM then launches the game

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\launching shorts>cd "C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2"

C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2>"Pinball FX2.exe"

C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2>REM   start a loop where the batch seees if the game is running and leaves the screen alone.

C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2>tasklist   | FIND "Pinball FX2.exe"  1>nul
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2>IF ERRORLEVEL 1(

C:\Program Files\Pinball FX2>
```

sorry if this seems trivial....I've never had to post before and learned alot of this in the 90s.

Comment: It should be `if errorlevel 1`, not `if %errorlevel% 1`. Also, an `else` needs to be on the same line as the `)` from the previous `if` statement

Comment: `IF ERRORLEVEL 1(` - give it a space (the parser is a bit picky at times): `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (`

Comment: There is no `sleep` command in Windows CMD…

Comment: SomethingDark :   not sure what happened...but I copied code from the notepad...adnthose %%'s appeared.   not in original code.   else is also true...will update completed working code

Stephan:  this fixed it, for sure.  

aschipfl:  this also seems to be true...but the code executes without bothering anything so I might just remove SLEEP altogether.